# Jenkins and Centos7 dotnet not found problem

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, centos

Firstly, our system consists of CENTOS 7 and docker. I have installed .NET SDK 6.0.3 and I created a Jenkins container on docker by using Jenkins:lts image. But I can not use dotnet command on jenkins.

```
dotnet build

/tmp/jenkins17157563865400019439.sh: 3: dotnet: not found

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I use dotnet command on Jenkins container?

Comment: How did you install .NET? What does your Dockerfile look like? You said you are running Jenkins in a container; how do you expect it to find the .NET installation you did?

Answer (score 0):

As with **EVERY** other Unix (or Windows) command, it's either got to be in your `$PATH` or you need to explicitly state the `/path/to/executable`.

Comment: Can you share some documentation or link as an example because I don't have enough knowledge about this kind of system but ı am trying to learn.

Comment: See @omajid's comment.